# I installed windows 8.1 and ubuntu 14.10 only windows 8 boots

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 14.10, windows-8, mbr

I had a windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.10 then i upgraded windows 7 to 8.1 now I cant get Ubuntu to boot

I now have grub but grub will not find Ubuntu

http://paste.ubuntu.com/11019932

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/11019932

Answer (score 0):

You encountered Redmond's idea that Windows should be the only OS on your hard disk. When you installed 8.1, the installation disk overwrote the boot manager and made Windows the default OS. There is a simple fix using [Ubuntu Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair). Go to the web page and download the iso image. Create a boot CD and then start your system with the CD. When you have repaired the boot manager, you should be able to boot into either OS.

Answer (score 0):

If Ubuntu still exists on your HDD, boot from Ubuntu live CD and use the commands below to install boot-repair.

Connect to the Internet.

Open a new Terminal, and run:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kranich/cubuntu
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

Then click Recommended Repair.

Comment: All that did was install grub find the windows partitions and not put Ubuntu into grub loader [http://paste.ubuntu.com/11019932](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11019932)